# How do you copy and paste keyframes from one Rig to another?

Tags: animation, keyframes

How do you copy and paste keyframes from one Rig to another?

I opened a walk cycle on a loop that I made.  I tried to copy and paste the walk cycle to sevral characters that I have, but I'm stuck at how to do it.  Any advise or suggestions?  Thanks in advance!

Rick

Answer (score 2):

**Link** the *Animation Data*.

- Select object **without the keyframes** first.
- Select the object **with the keyframes** to be copied second by holding <kbd>shift</kbd> and left clicking.
- Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>
- Select ***"Animation Data"***

This has in effect, *copied* the animation data from the second object to the first. *Note that you **must** change the current frame of the animation for the cache to update, change to take effect!*

**This method works for rigs as long as the names of the bones are the same!** *Please note that the same animation data may not affect two different rigs the same way, if they are not identical in bone rotation, location, and scaling.*

*(Also, please note that this may not work for complex objects or movements, like armatures or movement that effects individual vertices, unless they are identical. Blender will do it's best, but on objects or armatures with different geometries, it does not know which vertices to effect unless the movement is simple directional and rotational movement applied to the object as a whole. Your best method would be to map the data with a modifier.)*

Comment: Thanks but I was really saying rigs not objects sorry

Comment: This method will work for armatures, as long as they are virtually identical. Meaning, if the armatures have the same number of bones, with the same names, it will work. I just tested this, creating two armatures by hand, and copying the data. It worked just fine even though the armatures were not the same shape. It worked as expected.

Comment: I then tested with two totally different armatures, with different bone counts, sizes, and shapes. I then named some of the bones in the second armature after bones in the first armature, and copied the data. Indeed, it seems as though the data from the first armature's bones of the same name were applied to the second armature. The result was not exactly as I expected, and the movement seemed to be mirrored along the y axis. However, this is to be expected as the armatures are totally different, and the same rotational and directional data affects bones of different scale differently.

Comment: In essence, this method seems to work for anything, as well as can be expected, as long as the names are correct and there is a reasonable way for Blender to map the data.

Answer (score 2):

Open up the dope sheet from your armature, copy the keyframes, select your other rig and paste it in the dope sheet.

Comment: This method is good for transferring keyframes of one specific parameter to another, such as two different animated nodes inside a material. It's worth mentioning that the new parameter must be given at least one keyframe first for it to appear in the Dope Sheet and become available to paste into.